# Wait for queue to be full in RabbitMQ using Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, rabbitmq, es6-promise

I have a piece of code where I consume events from RabbitMQ and save the events(3 types of events A,B,C) into 2 different databases A,B. I can push into Database A without any problem but I need to wait for no of events to be at least 100 to push events of type B & C into database or until the code is trying to fill up the queue for last 5 minutes from the point saveToDb in invoked. I am not able to figure out how to wait for events for B and C and then save data in database.

Note that Event A will go into Database A and Event B,C will go into Database B.

I have written following piece of code.

```
import { Channel, ConsumeMessage } from 'amqplib';

const BATCH_SIZE = 100;

var eventBQueue = [];
var eventAQueue = [];

const shiftElements = (message) => {

    if ( message.length >= BATCH_SIZE) {
        const batch= message.splice(0, BATCH_SIZE);
        return batch;
    }
    return message;
}

const saveToDb = async (messages, database) => {
    const eventsA = filterEventsA(messages);
    const eventsB = filterEventsB(messages);
    const eventsC = filterEventsC(eventsB);

    const promises = [];
    promises.push(databaseAsync.publish(eventsC));


    if (eventBQueue.length < BATCH_SIZE) { 
        eventBQueue.push.apply(eventBQueue, eventsB);
    }
    else { 
        var eventsBBatched = shiftElements(eventBQueue);
        promises.push(database.publish(eventsBBatched, EVENTS_TABLE_A));
    }

    if (eventAQueue.length < BATCH_SIZE) {
        eventAQueue.push.apply(eventAQueue, eventsA);
    }
    else {
        var eventsABatched = shiftElements(eventAQueue);
        promises.push(database.publish(eventsABatched, EVENTS_TABLE_B));
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all(promises).then(resolve).catch(reject);
    });
}

export const process = async (database,
    rabbitmq): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        rabbitmq.consume(async (channel, message: ConsumeMessage) => {
            const messages = somefunction(message);
            await saveToDb(messages,database)
                .then(_ => {
                    try {
                        channel.ack(message)
                    } catch (error) {

                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    try {
                        console.error('error');
                        channel.ack(message)
                    } catch (error) {

                    }
                });
        });
        somefunction(resolve)
    });
}
```

Now I want to add some condition in `if` where `no of events < Batch_SIZE` to wait for data from rabbitMQ and to save in database when eventAQueue and eventBQueue has adequate size or there is a time limit waiting for this data. But I am not sure how to add it.

Comment: As it stands you have events types A,B,C and databases A,B, with no apparant reason to reuse "A" and "B". Suggest you edit question to better explain, or edit code and question to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: You say "wait for no of events to be at least 50" but `BATCH_SIZE = 100`. Is that intentional?

Comment: "or unless there is a timeout of 5 minutes". Do you mean "or until after a timeout of 5 minutes"? And if so, 5 minutes from what point?

Comment: Question starts off talking about "save the events" and ends with "send data" without having introduced either "send" or "data". Are *saving events* and *sending data* actually the same thing?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I have made the change to question itself to make it more clear.Though I would like to clear it here also.

1. I had to abstract few lines of code from the snippet so made that error in BATCH_SIZE. I meant it as at least 100 only.

2. By 5 minutes I meant from the time the event starts coming in the queue.

3. Yes "save the events" and "send data" mean the same thing. I mean that to send events to save it in the database. I cleared it in the question also.

Comment: tanmay_freak, your question is much clearer now and will hopefully attract answers. I wonder if it might be simpler to write a Class, eg `UploadBuffer()` with methods such as `enqueue()`, `upload()` and `startTimer()`. Then you will have encapsulated all the desired behaviour and you can create three instances of the class, one for each of your message types A, B and C.

Comment: What are the two `channel.ack(message)` statements supposed to acknowledge? Is it:
(i) that `message` has been received (which is synchronous, and makes sense)?
(ii) that `message` has been queued (which is synchronous, and makes less sense)?
(iii) that `message` has been saved (which is asynchronous, and makes no sense)?
As the code currently stands, it appears that you have attempted (iii).
Why would the message server need acknowledgement of anything other than receipt of a message?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 if the message is not saved and I don't want to acknowledge it. That way I can re-read the message unless it is saved so that message is not lost since it is important to save them.

Comment: From the line `const messages = somefunction(message)`, do I understand correctly that each `message` is actually multiple messages and that you want to enqueue all those multiple messages?

Comment: Yes, in `const messages = somefunction(message)` , each `message` consists of multiple messages and I want to enque all of them after filtering from `somefunction`.

Comment: Had a play with some code earlier and one thing became apparant. You need to be careful with error handling. In `saveToDb(events).then().catch((error) => {...})`, it is easy to write, as I did, an error handler that is passed an error arising from *anywhere* in the queue - not necessarily from the `message` seen in the closure.
The code in the question (when debugged) may suffer from the same issue. Part of the solution, I guess, would be to enqueue the messages (events?) in their original bundles and to save them bundle by bundle.

Comment: I see. Yeah maybe I can try to handle error in a better way. But I need to enqueue the messages after their separation only as I need to batch the individual events.

Comment: I think the issue arises because "BATCH_SIZE" is kind of dual-purpose; 
(i) it acts as a threshold at which an upload is triggered; 
(ii) it determines the size of upload batches.
Theses two concepts probably need to be separated and you may well have design decision(s) to make. 
For me (with limited understanding of the application) the simplest approach would be to re-designate "BATCH_SIZE" as "THRESHOLD" and always upload in bundles corresponding to the batches in which the message/events arrived.